# Infinite lazy bitmap

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I am trying to construct a lazy data structure that holds an infinite bitmap. I would like to support the following operations:

1. `true :: InfBitMap`

   Returns an infinite bitmap of True, i.e. all positions should have value True.
2. `falsify :: InfBitMap -> [Int] -> InfBitMap`

   Set all positions in the list to False. The list is possible infinite. For example, falsify true [0,2..] will return a list where all (and only) odd positions are True.
3. `check :: InfBitMap -> Int -> Bool`

   Check the value of the index.

Here is what I could do so far.

```
-- InfBitMap will look like [(@), (@, @), (@, @, @, @)..]
type InfBitMap = [Seq Bool]

true :: InfBitMap
true = iterate (\x -> x >< x) $ singleton True

-- O(L * log N) where N is the biggest index in the list checked for later
-- and L is the length of the index list. It is assumed that the list is
-- sorted and unique.
falsify :: InfBitMap -> [Int] -> InfBitMap
falsify ls is = map (falsify' is) ls
     where
         -- Update each sequence with all indices within its length
         -- Basically composes a list of (update pos False) for all positions
         -- within the length of the sequence and then applies it.
         falsify' is l = foldl' (.) id
                                (map ((flip update) False)
                                     (takeWhile (< length l) is))
                         $ l
-- O(log N) where N is the index.
check :: InfBitMap -> Int -> Bool
check ls i = index (fromJust $ find ((> i) . length) ls) i
```

I am wondering if there is some Haskellish concept/data-structure that I am missing that would make my code more elegant / more efficient (constants do not matter to me, just order). I tried looking at Zippers and Lenses but they do not seem to help. I would like to keep the complexities of updates and checks logarithmic (maybe just amortized logarithmic).

Note: before someone suspects it, no this is not a homework problem!

**Update**:

It just occurred to me that check can be improved to:

```
-- O(log N) where N is the index.
-- Returns "collapsed" bitmap for later more efficient checks.
check :: InfBitMap -> Int -> (Bool, InfBitMap)
check ls i = (index l i, ls')
    where
        ls'@(l:_) = dropWhile ((<= i) . length) ls
```

Which can be turned into a Monad for code cleanliness.

Comment: Are you sure about `InfBitMap`? If `true` should be isomorphic to `repeat True`, `InfBitMap` would need to be a `[Bool]` or `Seq Bool`, but not both.

Comment: @Zeta I did not mean true to be isomorphic to repeat True. I mean it holds an infinite sequence of True's. If it were isomorphic to repeat True, that would make check linear in N.

Comment: Complexity for `falsify` doesn't seem right. There are `L` updates for an `N` length sequence, which is O(L * log N) already.

Comment: @AndrásKovács in the first sequence there's at most 1 update, in the second at most 2, ..., in the kth there's at most 2^k updates. Summing over, one gets the number of updates <= 2^(k + 1). Notice that k = max(log log N, log L). This accounts for the updates. One also needs to account for traversing the chain, this is at most log N steps.

Comment: @aelguindy for `Data.Sequence` a single update is log N in the size. I don't quite understand from where the "+" in "L + log N" comes from.

Comment: @AndrásKovács whoops you are right. I got confused. Edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A slight variation on the well-known [integer trie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-inttrie) seems to be applicable here.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Trie a = Trie a (Trie a) (Trie a) deriving (Functor)

true :: Trie Bool
true = Trie True true true

-- O(log(index))
check :: Trie a -> Int -> a
check t i | i < 0 = error "negative index"
check t i = go t (i + 1) where
    go (Trie a _ _) 1 = a
    go (Trie _ l r) i = go (if even i then l else r) (div i 2)

--O(log(index))
modify :: Trie a -> Int -> (a -> a) -> Trie a
modify t i f | i < 0 = error "negative index"
modify t i f = go t (i + 1) where
    go (Trie a l r) 1 = Trie (f a) l r
    go (Trie a l r) i | even i = Trie a (go l (div i 2)) r
    go (Trie a l r) i = Trie a l (go r (div i 2))
```

Unfortunately we can't use `modify` to implement `falsify` because we can't handle infinite lists of indices that way (all modifications have to be performed before an element of the trie can be inspected). Instead, we should do something more like a merge:

```
ascIndexModify :: Trie a -> [(Int, a -> a)] -> Trie a
ascIndexModify t is = go 1 t is where
    go _ t [] = t
    go i t@(Trie a l r) ((i', f):is) = case compare i (i' + 1) of
        LT -> Trie a (go (2*i) l ((i', f):is)) (go (2*i+1) r ((i', f):is))
        GT -> go i t is
        EQ -> Trie (f a) (go (2*i) l is) (go (2*i+1) r is)

falsify :: Trie Bool -> [Int] -> Trie Bool
falsify t is = ascIndexModify t [(i, const False) | i <- is]
```

We assume strictly ascending indices in `is`, since otherwise we would skip places in the trie or even get non-termination, for example in `check (falsify t (repeat 0)) 1`.

The time complexities are a bit complicated by laziness. In `check (falsify t is) index`, we pay an additional cost of a constant `log 2 index` number of comparisons, and a further `length (filter (<index) is)` number of comparisons (i. e. the cost of stepping over all indices smaller than what we're looking up). You could say it's `O(max(log(index), length(filter (<index) is))`. Anyway, it's definitely better than the `O(length is * log (index))` that we would get for a `falsify` implemented for finite `is`-es using `modify`.

We must keep in mind that tree nodes are evaluated once, and subsequent `check`-s for the same index after the first `check` are not paying any extra cost for `falsify`. Again, laziness makes this a bit complicated.

This `falsify` is also pretty well-behaved when we want to traverse a prefix of a trie. Take this `toList` function:

```
trieToList :: Trie a -> [a]
trieToList t = go [t] where
    go ts = [a | Trie a _ _ <- ts] 
            ++ go (do {Trie _ l r <- ts; [l, r]})
```

It's a standard breadth-first traversal, in linear time. The traversal time remains linear when we compute `take n $ trieToList (falsify t is)`, since `falsify` incurs at most `n + length (filter (<n) is)` extra comparisons, which is at most `2 * n`, assuming strictly increasing `is`.

(side note: the space requirement of breadth-first traversal is rather painful, but I can't see a simple way to help it, since iterative deepening is even worse here, because there the whole tree must be held in memory, while bfs only has to remember the bottom level of the tree).

Answer (score 0):

One way to represent this is as a function.

```
true = const True

falsify ls is = \i -> not (i `elem` is) && ls i

check ls i = ls i
```

The true and falsify functions are nice and efficient. The check function can be as bad as linear. It's possible to improve the efficiency of the same basic idea. I like its elegance.